# How do I select a specific json string from a url for displaying in a webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, android-webview, android-json

I am getting a json string parameter from my javascript files as follows :

```
http://local/action/?action=loadFile&params=%7B%22fileChart%22%3A%22url%22%2C%22item%22%3A%7B%22DocId%22%3A%2270078903%22%2C%22Headline%22%3A%22Alert%253A%2520AAPL%253A%2520QA%2520Test%22%2C%22PrimaryTickers%22%3A%22AAPL.O%22%2C%22ArrivalDate%22%3A%222015-04-29T08%3A04%3A40Z%22%2C%22fileType%22%3A%22url%22%2C%22secondaryFileType%22%3A%22pdf%22%2C%22secondaryFileExtension%22%3A%22pdf%22%2C%22curDate%22%3A1435589346483%2C%22Pages%22%3A8%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%253A%252F%252Fuat.citivelocity.com%252Frendition%252Feppublic%252FdocumentService%252FdXNlcl9pZD0mYWN0aW9uPXZpZXc%252FZmlsZV9uYW1lPVZTNkoucGRm%22%2C%22contributor%22%3A%22Citi%20-%20Linkback%20Test%22%7D%7D&requestType=GET&timestamp=1435589346484
```

I want to display only the url part of the above url, such that I can decode https for the given link and display only the required link in a webview loadurl.  In the case of the above link it's : https://uat.citvelocity.com ..etc , 
The current idea I got from searching online is something like this :

```
webview.loadurl("javascript:(function() { "| "document.getElementByTagName('url')[0].style.display="+";"+"})()"); }
});
```

But that doesn't work as expected. Am I doing it wrong? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your string is JSON, it's probably a good idea to just parse that JSON into an object so you can just use the objects properties to get whatever you want.

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent('http://local/action/?action=loadFile&params=%7B%22fileChart%22%3A%22url%22%2C%22item%22%3A%7B%22DocId%22%3A%2270078903%22%2C%22Headline%22%3A%22Alert%253A%2520AAPL%253A%2520QA%2520Test%22%2C%22PrimaryTickers%22%3A%22AAPL.O%22%2C%22ArrivalDate%22%3A%222015-04-29T08%3A04%3A40Z%22%2C%22fileType%22%3A%22url%22%2C%22secondaryFileType%22%3A%22pdf%22%2C%22secondaryFileExtension%22%3A%22pdf%22%2C%22curDate%22%3A1435589346483%2C%22Pages%22%3A8%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%253A%252F%252Fuat.citivelocity.com%252Frendition%252Feppublic%252FdocumentService%252FdXNlcl9pZD0mYWN0aW9uPXZpZXc%252FZmlsZV9uYW1lPVZTNkoucGRm%22%2C%22contributor%22%3A%22Citi%20-%20Linkback%20Test%22%7D%7D&requestType=GET&timestamp=1435589346484'),
    json = JSON.parse(decoded.slice(decoded.indexOf('&params=') + 8, decoded.indexOf('&requestType'))),
    url = decodeURIComponent(json.item.url);
```

Comment: The thing is the given json url http://local/action/..etc is dynamic, so it keeps changing, but the string url within it containing the https remains the same ,with varying https url's , is it possible to recognize if the params contain https, then get the string starting from https, decode it and display it in a webview loadurl?

Comment: the local/action can change as much as it wants. We only check the index of the 'params=' and 'responseType=', which I suspect will stay the same if every dynamic url comes from the same source, so nothing changes. Ofc you can just like cut the string into pieces, but since the data  is json , it makes more sense to use the json imho.